# Meta Insights API - show Spend of all campaigns in USD

Tags: currency, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights, usd

I've been trying to pull out the spend of each ad campaign using the Meta Insights API, but the spend comes out as the currency as stated in the account_currency field.

When creating a report through Ads Reporting in Ads Manager, there's an option to 'Standardise Currency' and select USD, so all the 'Amount Spent' is shown as USD.

Is there a way that I could get the spend from the API all in USD as well?

Answer (score 0):

Their documentation says its available. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/currency/

```
usd_exchange
The exchange rate between the person's preferred currency and US Dollars
```

I had the same issue as I had multiple ad accounts of different currency. To convert the currency to USD, I created a Currency Converter function from any currency to USD.

```
//Currency Convert to USD
function ConvertUSD($amount, $from)
{
    $response_json   = file_get_contents("https://api.exchangerate-api.com/v4/latest/" . $from);
    $response_object = json_decode($response_json);
    $usd             = round(($amount * $response_object->rates->USD), 2);
    return $usd;
}

$from = $ad_account["currency"]; //GBP
$amount = 100; 
//Call the function where you need USD value 
ConvertUSD($amount,$from);
```

List of Supported countries
https://www.exchangerate-api.com/docs/supported-currencies